# How can I access a custom object inside an exception?

Tags: c#, exception

In the debugger I can see that an exception has an object containing error details. The object is defined like this:

```
[System.ServiceModel.FaultException<xxx.ValidationDetails[]>]
```

How do i access that object in code?

Comment: please provide the code, where the exception is handled

Comment: Can you supply the exception itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FaultException<TDetail>` generic class has a property:

```
TDetail Detail
```

So you just need to access the [Detail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575596(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which in your example will be of type `xxx.ValidationDetails[]`